# python 1d arrays how to dictate size with pre entered figure

Tags: arrays

so i am coding something and i am unable to get my array to work since it isnt working and coming up with error messages i am attempting to get a value from the user and that value is how many spaces the array has but it isnot working as of this moment

```
number = input("how many words do you want to get the avarage length of? :")
    words = [str()] * number
```

the error message is
line 8, in 
array_testing()
line 3, in array_testing
words = [str()] * number
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The error message means just what it says, and is correct. `input('')` returns a string, such as `'4'`.  `str()` returns ''.  So the expression is something like `['']*'4'`.  Replace `number` in the expression with `int(number)`.